# Template and xml

Tags: xml, templates

I'm building an xml I'd like to clean up a bit.

I mean, some attributes have very long string values:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource 
        driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://${dataimporter.request.host};databaseName=giac_txt"
        user="${dataimporter.request.user}"
        password="${dataimporter.request.password}"
    />
    
    <document>
        <entity name="item" query="select 'geac_txt' as source, codi_arxiu, codi_fons, codi_doc as codi_unitat, titol from anc_documents union all select 'geac_txt' as source, codi_arxiu, codi_fons, codi_unitat as codi_unitat, titol from anc_unicat">
            <field column="source" name="source_s"/>
            <field column="codi_arxiu" name="arxiu_l"/>
            <field column="codi_fons" name="fons_l"/>
            <field column="codi_unitat" name="codi_l"/>
            <field column="titol" name="titol_txt_ca" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I'm looking for a way:

1. any templating tool, or
2. any xml application transformation.

I don't quite to pick the right tool yet.

I'd like to have separated files with literal values and then merge them to main document.

I mean, some template engines are libraries that are fitted to any language like python, java...

I'm looking for any tool to that with out using any code, only templates...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Any programming language you or your team already know will have XML parsing libraries that will enable you to build support for templates.  There's not enough detail in your question to provide much more guidance beyond in general suggesting that you use what you know and be sure to use an existing XML parsing library – hand-parsing or using regular expressions with XML should absolutely be avoided.

An alternative, which you should at least be aware of, is XSLT.

XSLT is the ultimate language for such shuffling of values to, from, and between XML documents, including templates – in fact, XML *templates* are a core construct.  XSLT's semantics are unconventional in drawing from declarative, functional, and rule-based paradigms; its syntax is unconventionally XML-based. (Although initially daunting, these characteristics are actually powerful advantages once the learning curve is overcome.)  Once mastered, its power and applicability scale from simple scripts to complex transformations between substantially disparate data formats and standards.

Comment: I've took a look on XSLT... I'm not sure it's suitable at all for me. I mean, I only need to keep organized my long sql queries outside of my xml... I don't need to transform any previous xml...

Comment: XSLT can combine an XML template with separately-stored SQL attribute values to produce your sample XML very easily (assuming there's some actual value to you in doing so).

Comment: Anyway, this is a very high-level answer in response to your very high-level question about templates in XML.  Anything beyond that and you're setting up for an extended dialog that would start by challenging why you need to "keep organized my long sql queries outside of my xml."  Multiple back-and-forth exchanges later, you probably will realize that you asked about a [solution Y when you should have really asked about problem X](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/234215) (or that there's no actual problem at all).  Moving on.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a quick example for you of how this can be done in XSLT (but without knowing exactly what you want to do to clean up this XML). You can see it in operation, and play around with it, at

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEJbVr3

This is the latest version, XSLT 3.0. Take care because there are many XSLT processors around that only implement version 1.0, which is much less powerful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="true"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="entity/@query">
      <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ',\s+')">
          <queryPart>{.}</queryPart>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How it works:

- The `<xsl:mode>` declaration says "by default, process every element and attribute by shallow-copying it, unless you find a more specific rule"
- The `<xsl:template>` declaration says "when you find an attribute named `query` whose containing element is named `entity`, split the value up on comma separators, and for each token, output a `queryPart` element containing that token."

Comment: Thanks @Michael .Probably I've not explained so well... My xml above would be the final xml. I like to remove the very long query attribute value by any variable reference...

Comment: So you're trying to design a better XML representation of your data? We can't help you with that without a deep understanding of the data you are trying to represent; and anything that requires a deep understanding of your problem domain is outside the scope of StackOverflow.